# Parity: Change port 30304?

Tags: parity, discovery-protocol, ports

If I want to change the discovery port from 30303 to XXXX I do "parity -port XXXX".  But what if I want to change 30304/udp?

For example, maybe I have many computers NAT behind a firewall.  I can do port forwarding for the discovery port 30303, XXXX, etc. and invoke those individually on the command line.  But how do I do this with 30304/udp?